# How do I remove a Maven dependency that my dependency is pulling in but only in test scope?

Tags: java, maven, log4j

My code has a dependency on an old external piece of code that still uses the vulnerable versions of Log4J.  I was able to remove the sub-dependency by adding:

`<exclusions><exclusion><groupId>log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions>`

And now it does not appear when I do `mvn dependency:tree`.  However, when I do `mvn clean install` it downloads `log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:test`.

How do I prevent my dependency from downloading log4j-1.2?

Comment: It might being referernced by another artifact? You need a version because it's used ... you have to provide are more recent version of that..

Comment: @khmarbaise I have log4j-2.17.1 and log4j-1.2-api (the bridge API) in my pom to provide for that.

Comment: I would say there is a problem..log4j-1.2-api?? https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api-separation.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not evil to download a vulnerable version if you do not include it in your application.

Secondly, the download can not only be a transitive dependency of your application, but may also be a dependency of one of the Maven plugins you are running.

Building with the `-X` flag may give you more information.